# WCF, Mtom Message Encoding, The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config

Let me explain you from the begining. There are 3 projects in my solution explorer window in `Visual Studio`. Let me explain them one by one. First one is Web Project(ASP.NET Form Based). I need to get some data from 2 different sources. So I have added two different WCF projects in to my solution explorer window in `Visual Studio`.

Let me tell you about these 2 WCF projects. First WCF is connected to SOAP web service. Message Encoding type should be Mtom for this SOAP service. By the way this SOAP web service returns byte data(like picture). That's why I have right clicked and then Add> Service Reference option to complete this operation. 
And as you known this operation updates Web.config file automatically. That's why you see ' binding="wsHttpBinding"  ' in Web.config file.

Beside this there is one more WCF project like I mention above. But this works well. I don't have any problem with it.

I have added these two WCF projects in to my Web Project with right clicking Add>Service Reference option. Actually it was working fine until i have try it with large byte data(picture) Let me explain with data sizes: First WCF project is able to bring me a data(picture) with a small size 1.84 KB (1,890 bytes). But same WCF project is not able to bring me a data(picture) with a larger size 164 KB (168,423 bytes). This is the problem. That's why I have shared web.config file of the web project and the web.config file of the First WCF project.

I'm sharing web.config files that are giving errors when displaying a large photo. (You can see web.config file of the web project and web.config file of the first WCF project below)

I have founded&tried lots of solution. But I am still getting same error.

**Here is the error:**

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element
```

IIS Version of the web server is: Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS: Version 8.5.9600.16384. I have made a research about this problem. I have found&tried lots of solution. But it did not work.

**Here is the web.config file of the WCF project**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="abcdPortBinding">
          <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureHttpBinding" 
          closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
          openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://abc.abc.com:443/abc-srv/abcPort"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="abcdPortBinding"
        contract="mobilSignatureServiceReference.abcdsrv" name="abcdPort" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Servicebehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Servicebehavior" name="abcdWcfServisi.abcdServisim">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding" name="SecureHttp" contract="abcdWcfServisi.IabcdServisim"/>
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"/>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Here is the Web.config file of the web project(asp.net form based project)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <machineKey validation="3DES"/>
    <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" enableViewStateMac="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true"/>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
    <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="myHttpModule" type="myHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="abc" loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="abc.aspx" timeout="50000"/>
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="https://abctest.com">
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="abc.aspx"/>
        <add value="abcSecureSrv.svc"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://abctest.com/abc.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding_abcd" 
          closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" 
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
          sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8" 
          transferMode="Streamed" 
          messageEncoding="Text" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureHttp" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://abctest.com/abcdesube.svc?wsdl"
        behaviorConfiguration="SertifikaDavranisi" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding_abcd" contract="abcdesube"
        name="HttpBinding_abcd" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:37377/abcdServisim.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="SecureHttp" contract="abcdSignature.IabcdServisim"
        name="SecureHttp" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SertifikaDavranisi">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SertifikaDavranisi">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<httpsTransport..>` tag has solved the problem.

```
<customBinding>
<binding> 
 <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>    
 </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you call the service, by adding service reference? it seems that you call the service in the web project. but why does the WCF project have the Client section? This indicates that the WCF project has referred to other projects.
I would like to know that the detail steps you take in the client-side for calling the service, including the service metadata URL you typed.
Besides, try to remove all other irrelevant project configuration and adding the service reference again and share it with me.  these configurations appear not generated automatically.
Look forward to your reply.
**Updated.**
I suggest you create a new console application to test again and remove irrelevant configuration in the WCF project. please replace the `system.servicemodel` configuration with the below code.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated my post like you said.

Comment: Why does your first Webconfig file of the WCF project have the client section? Does it generate the client proxy and fetch data from it? Is it possible that we need to apply the settings on this binding, namely Custombidning?
Besides, there are two client service endpoints in the webconfig file of your web project. which one did you call to return the data of the picture?

Comment: Your First Question: Why does your first Webconfig file of the WCF project have the client section? First i have created a web project and then I have added a WCF project. And then right click on WCF Project>Service Reference option. I wrote SOAP link that returns me picture data in this window. I have completed adding service reference like this way. And all these actions created this web.config file automatically(first web config file in my post) I did not change anything on this web.config file. @Abraham Qian

Comment: Your Second Question: Besides, there are two client service endpoints in the webconfig file of your web project. which one did you call to return the data of the picture? Here is the reply: This one: <endpoint address="http://localhost:37377/abcdServisim.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttp" contract="abcdSignature.IabcdServisim" name="SecureHttp" /> Of course I have changed real address link and contract detail with dummy things because sharing is not allowed by company.

Comment: The overall configuration does not seem to have any problems, although the client configuration is not required, but try to apply your configuration on the client’s wshttpbinding.
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureHttp" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

Comment: Change to,                                                                     <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureHttp" 
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>

Comment: I have opened web.config file of the Web project(client) And I have updated like you wrote above And then I run the code with debug option. But It gave me same error again: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element